# Laravel Csrf Token fails when i change Homestead date

Tags: php, laravel

I need to test some feature in differents dates, so I set differents dates in my Homestead vm, but when i try to refresh the page, it redirect me to the login and then i cant login in my system because i get a TokenMismatchException. I am using Laravel 5.4

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: What part of my code do you want to see?

Comment: You can start with the block that throws exception. You can also share possible related parts. It may help people to clearify the details.